# Integrating function with 4th power

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Please help me to integrate the following fraction...

$$\frac{v-1}{v(1+(v-1)^{4})}$$

I can dissociate it into two parts but then I can't continue...

Comment: **Hint:** Partial Fractions.

Comment: What two parts?

Comment: @saulspatz...I divide it with numerators v and 1 with the same denominators...But then I can't proceed...I'm confused with the 4th power.Even if I factorize it,it becomes complicated...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use $u=v-1$ substitution then you can partialy integrate with $a=x$ and $\frac{d}{du}b=\frac{1}{(u+1)^5}$.